# Two buttons for one script JS in web

Tags: javascript, performance, ejs

I want to put a button/a for each record and run script for that concrete record but i stuck.

Button/a:

```
<a class="record-delete" data-doc="<%= shop._id %>">
   <img src="/trashcan.svg" alt="delete icon" />
</a>
```

Script:

```
const trashcan = document.querySelector('a.record-delete');
trashcan.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const endpoint = `/shops/${trashcan.dataset.doc}`;
        fetch(endpoint, {
             method: 'DELETE'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => window.location.href = data.redirect)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
```

Script works only for last record. I know that i can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll
```

Instead of:

```
document.querySelector
```

But I don't have any idea how to run script for concrete button/a, as it still need **concrete** variable/target.

Thank you in advance for help if You can ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will help, https://jsfiddle.net/px59m3t2/

```js
const trashcans = [...document.querySelectorAll('a.record-delete')];

trashcans.forEach(trashcan => {
  trashcan.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    alert(e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-doc'));
  });
});
```